# Build custom URLs with custom route data in MVCSiteMapProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

We are using MVCSiteMapProvider for our website.

Here is the scenario...
Imagine a page for employee, `/employee/123`.  This would have employee details as well as a set of links that need to maintain the `123` in the url.

Some of the links need to point to legacy urls, so something like `/demographics/?employeeID=123`, would be a  case.  There are about 30 of these links, so maintaining these in the sitemap would be imperative.

Any suggestions on how to approach this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a DynamicNodeProvider to handle this scenario. You just need to add the "related" nodes when looping through so they all appear grouped together. The id is stored in the RouteValues and cached for all users, so the sitemap won't forget it between requests.

```
public class EmployeeDynamicNodeProvider
    : DynamicNodeProviderBase
{
    CRUDExample db = new CRUDExample();

    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node)
    {
        var result = new List<DynamicNode>();

        var employees = db.Employee;
        foreach (var employee in employees)
        {
            var employeeKey = "Product_" + employee.Id.ToString();

            // Create the "Details" node for the employee
            var employeeNode = new DynamicNode(employeeKey, "EmployeeParentNodeKey", employee.Name, employee.Name, "Employee", "Details");

            // Set the "id" route value so the match will work.
            employeeNode.RouteValues.Add("id", employee.Id);

            // Add the node to the result
            result.Add(employeeNode);


            // Create the "Edit" node for the employee
            var employeeEditNode = new DynamicNode("EmployeeEdit_" + employee.Id.ToString(), employeeKey, "Edit", "Edit", "Employee", "Edit");

            // Set the "id" route value of the edit node
            employeeEditNode.RouteValues.Add("id", employee.Id);

            // Add the node to the result
            result.Add(employeeEditNode);


            // Create the "Delete" node for the employee
            var employeeDeleteNode = new DynamicNode("EmployeeDelete_" + employee.Id.ToString(), employeeKey, "Delete", "Delete", "Employee", "Delete");

            // Set the "id" route value of the delete node
            employeeDeleteNode.RouteValues.Add("id", employee.Id);

            // Add the node to the result
            result.Add(employeeDeleteNode);


            // Create the "Demographics" node for the employee
            var employeeDemographicsNode = new DynamicNode("EmployeeDemographics_" + employee.Id.ToString(), employeeKey, "Demographics", "Demographics", "Employee", "Demographics");

            // Set the "id" route value of the delete node
            employeeDemographicsNode.RouteValues.Add("id", employee.Id);

            // Add the node to the result
            result.Add(employeeDemographicsNode);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

As for the URLs, it is System.Web.Routing that converts the route values into URLs. However, you have a couple of other options if your URLs are complex:

1. Use the Url property of the sitemap node rather than route values.
2. Create a custom URL resolver to handle special cases of URLs.

Comment: Thank you, also thank you for your work on this project...  It's a great tool and I use it every day.